# Partial view not returning from controller action in development environment but it is loading in local

Tags: .net

I am returning a partial view from the controller and is working fine in local, but after publishing the code on server, it is not loading the partial view. It shows below error:

> /Monitoring/GetData:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

My Controller action is here that returns the partial view `GetData`:

```
public ActionResult GetData(string ID)
{
string studyIdentifier = ID;
var detailByPersonnel = (Session["PID"]);
var responseDetails = Session[detailByPersonnel + "_StudyDetails"];
Session[detailByPersonnel + "_studyIdentifier"] = studyIdentifier;
var response = (IList<MyDetailsEntity>)responseDetails;
var specificData = response.Where(x => x.ID == ID).ToList();
ViewBag.Data = specificData;
if (response == null)
{
    response = new List<MyDetailsEntity>();
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server error. Please try after some time.");
}
return PartialView(specificData);
}
```

We are calling above action method through button click using below code:

```
$('.SliderSty').on("click", function () {
  $('.SliderSty').css('opacity', '1');
  $("#breadcrumbs ul li:nth-child(2)").nextAll().remove();
  var sId = this.id;
  $("#mydata").load("/Monitoring/GetData", { ID: sId });
  $("#breadcrumbs ul").append("<li><a href=" + href + ">" + sId + "</a></li>");
  $("#ChartView").css('display', 'none');
  $("#GridView").css('display', 'none');
  $(this).siblings('.SliderSty').css('opacity', '.3');
  CreateTable();
});
```

Comment: When you deploy the code to the server, are you deploying it to its own website, or as an application within another site? ie: do you access it as `https://somesite/` or `https://somesite/yourapp/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to call like this:

```
`$("#mydata").load("../Monitoring/GetData", { ID: sId });`
```

Instead of:

```
`$("#mydata").load("/Monitoring/GetData", { ID: sId });`
```